# Drawing 3D animations in Python

Tags: python, graphics

Looking for a library or framework to aid me with the following:

I receive (x,y,z) vectors every few milliseconds telling me how an object is moving. I want to draw a point in the center of the screen to start, and have it move about - outlining its path - until I tell it to stop.

Being in 3D, I'd need some easy way to rotate or pan around this animation to get different perspectives.

Any recommendations for what to use in Python to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/).  I have been using it for 3d graphics plots.  It has a method scatterplot that is quick in updating a point on the screen.  You can also access the view with azimuth and elevation to orbit around the object.  http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glscatterplotitem.html it uses pyopengl underneath, but its a fast and simple way to access those functions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [PyOpenGL](http://freecode.com/projects/pyopengl) will give you access directly to OpenGL from python.